# Installing a new graphics card on with my other one

Tags: windows, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

I have 1 gtx 1050 ti 2gb vram and i was wondering if i install another one but with 4 gb vram will that work and will the vram add up?

Comment: Depending on the motherboard you may use one or another or both simultaneously but in any case each one will use their VRAM.

Answer (score 1):

The 1050 Ti doesn't support SLi; I can imagine Gabriela's information is also correct, but there isn't a cumulative benefit. They would act independently of one another, which would improve performance of multiple monitors (cutting the workload by designating individual cards), but they wouldn't function as a combined unit. I know the closest model that does support SLi is the 1060, so you would be wanting two of those if you want to link your cards together.